# How to view return value of a system call in visual studio 2010 debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

[image]

There is no return value of SendMessage, how could I view the return value of SendMessage while debugging, without:
1.assign a temporary variable.
2.use EAX.

Thanks.

Comment: this problem is nonsense, since there are already two easy solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net you could do something like:

```
#if DEBUG then
   debug.print SendMessage(...)
#else
   SendMessage(...)
#end if
```

I think in C, it's #ifdef, but it's been a while since I've coded in C.